# сколько переменных word есть в коде

Tags: python

необходимо добавить к строке цифры

```
def new():
    word1 = '1'
    word2 = '2'
    word3 = '3'

    i = 1
    try:
        while i > 0:
            howmuchwords = print(word + str(1))
            print(howmuchwords)

    except cant_find_word4:
        print('helloword')
```

код я представляю себе примерно таким, он не рабочий, просто мое представление как может выглядеть.
Этим кодом я хочу понять сколько переменных word есть в коде ведь каждый раз их будет разное количество, от 1 до 999

Comment: Если у вас есть много однотипных элементов сложите их в массив и все. Кол-во можно просто методом `len` у массива посмотреть.

Comment: «...ведь каждый раз их будет разное количество» (с) — а каким образом кол-во переменных, созданных в функции, должно меняться? о_О

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
word1 = '1'
word2 = '2'
word3 = '3'

count = 0
for key in dict(locals()):
    if key.startswith('word'):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

А вообще однотипные элементы лучше сложить в список и все. Длину методом `len` смотреть.

Comment: как решение заданного вопроса полностью соответсвует (для надежности конечно стоило бы использовать регулярку `/^word\d+$/`), но возможно автору вопроса действительно стоит применять массив не известна мотивация подсчета

Comment: Я думаю, стоит все-таки показать как сделать через список - это нам с вами очевидно как это делать, а автору вопроса скорее всего нет, поэтому он и пытается посчитать переменные с одинаковым началом.

Answer (score 3):

Просто покажу для разнообразия, как можно в одну строку посчитать, используя методику из другого ответа и генераторное выражение:

```
print(sum(key.startswith('word') for key in dict(locals())))
```